# Обновление Windows Vista до Windows 7

Tags: обновления, windows

А разве WinVista Home Premium 32bit нельзя обновить до Win7 Home Premium 32bit? Я попытался, но ключ не подошел. Ключ с крышки ноута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вот: http://windows.microsoft.com/ru-RU/windows7/products/upgrade Но всё равно заново лицензию на семёрку покупать придётся! Несколько лет назад вроде, коробочные апгрейды продавались, стоили дешевле. Сейчас не знаю.А вот даунгрейд, как писал Malus, с Семёрки и Висты, возможен только до ХР.

Answer (score 1):

Наоборот можно, а так вроде нельзя)

Answer (score 0):

Бредовая затея, проще висту снести и установить на свеженький диск нулёвый 7ку.

Ибо виста изначально была очень тормознута, и её не обновлять нужно а сносить, причем сразу же.

Comment: А лицензия? Заказчик не хочет платить 4-5 ру-бля за лиц.